# MVC 5 - A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

Tags: validation, razor, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-views

I am developing an MVC5 internet application and have a question in regards to user input having HTML data.

I understand that if I want to have HTML code in a model, I can include the `[AllowHtml]` data annotation and then sanitize the objects field.

My question is this, for any object field that does not have the `[AllowHtml]` data annotation, where the user enters some HTML code, is it possible to cater to this error rather than have the `Error.cshtml` display the error?

Ideally, I would like to display a validation message in the view before the `Error.cshtml` displays and logs the error.

Is this possible? How can I cater to the error before the `Error.cshtml` displays and logs the error.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I have a function as follows in the `Global.asax` file:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

This function catches my errors such as when the user goes to a page that does not exist, however, the `http error` in question goes directly to the `error.cshtml` file.

How can I edit my code so that the `Application_Error` function catches this error?

I am using `Elmah` for logging and have `customErrors mode="On"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that easy to write a validator that checks if a textbox doesn't contain HTML. This is because HTML is not defined by certain characters, but instead by a combination of them. A text containing `<`,   '>' or even `<script>` isn't necessarily HTML.

You should take the approach of the allowed values. If a textbox should contain only number, then validate it like so.

By overriding `Application_Error` in `Global.asax` you can catch this exception and redirect the user to a more meaningful error page

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    Exception lastError = Server.GetLastError();
    if (lastError is HttpRequestValidationException)
    {
        //redirect to a static page and show proper error message
    }
}
```

If you're using Elmah things are even simpler. Elmah is designed to work with ASP.Net error handling.

You need to remove the default global `HandleErrorAttribute` from `App_Start\FilterConfig` (or `Global.asax`), and then set up an error page in your `Web.config`:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/error/" />
```

In case you run into trouble please check this article, it explains everything very well
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx

Comment: The Application_Error() function is still not catching the error, and instead, the error.cshtml is displayed.

Comment: I have added a protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) function to the controller, and this function catches the error. Is this how it should be done?

Comment: You should follow this link: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx